# How do I merge another developer's branch into mine?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am relatively new to git. Our organization uses a [Fork & Pull Model](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) for managing changes to the master branch. Each developer forks the master and branches from their fork when adding new features. I keep an eye on commits that other developers are making in their own branches, and would sometimes like to merge these changes into my own branch. What steps do I take to accomplish this?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You first need to add the other developer repository as a remote.

```
git remote add otherrep uriToOtherRep
```

Then you fetch changes from there

```
git fetch otherrep
```

And then you merge the branch from the remote repository into yours

```
git merge otherrep/branchname
```

Happy merging!

Comment: How to fetch files from `branch1` to `branch2` within same repo `repo`?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by "fetch". Suppose you are sitting on `branch1` and want to checkout a file from `branch2` you can simply use `git checkout branch2 -- /path/to/file`

Answer (score 38):

Let's say you are currently working on branch `feature/feature_a` and you want to merge the changes made in another branch called `feature/feature_b` to `feature/feature_a`. The following commands should do the trick:

```
git checkout feature/feature_b
git pull
git checkout feature/feature_a
git merge feature/feature_b
```

Answer (score 27):

You can also do "git pull", it'll pull the changes of all the branches.

> git pull

You can run git merge into your current branch

> git merge origin `<branchname>`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `origin <branch>` instead of 'origin/<branch>'

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I need to explicitly checkout and pull the branch I wish to merge. Git version 2.25.1.

Answer (score 9):

once you have the branch in question in your repository as, say, `anotherdev/master` remote branch, you do the `git merge anotherdev/master`.

Comment: How do I get the branch into my repository?

Comment: It depends on how your repositories are organized and whether you pull directly from the other dev or from some central repository branch. Anyway, it should be a result of some `git fetch`, though I can't tell you how your remotes should be configured.

Answer (score 1):

1. Git checkout branch1(Main branch from where you want to get the changes to your branch)
2. git pull (branchName1)
3. git checkout branch2(Here you want to merge all the branch 1 changes to branch2)
4. git merge branch1