# Pull other branch vs fetching and merging remote tracking branch?

Tags: git

The answers on most SO posts regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11582894/3813411) type of question, where I have some branch `a` checked out and want to merge in latest `master` from `origin`, seem to hint at one primary way of doing it. Namely:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

However, it seems like it would be more concise to do instead `git pull origin master`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20103414/3813411) answer seems to hint at there being some subtle differences but it seems like some of those were fixed like updating the tracking branch `origin/master` as well. So I'm wondering if there's any difference in the two or why the first way would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the more-finicky details depend on your Git version, which is what I'm noting in the answer to which you linked.  If you want to know the *precise* difference between various different Git commands, you need to specify the exact commands—including exact spellings of everything—*and* exact Git versions.

If you want the more general "what does this mostly do", `git pull` with *no options and arguments* mostly runs `git fetch` and then `git merge`, with the `fetch` part using the current branch's *remote*, and the merge part using the current branch's *upstream*.  So whether you do it as one command—`git pull`, with no arguments at all, or as two separate commands, `git fetch` and `git merge` also with no arguments at all—it will do the same thing.  Once you start adding various options and arguments, then we have to start getting picky about which Git version you have, and so on.

(You can of course configure `git pull` to run `git rebase` as its second command, in which case, substitute `git rebase` everywhere above.  The caveats about small differences that are version-dependent remain.  In some ways, they're worse: for instance, fork-point style rebase was initially introduced by `git pull` only, and then added to `git rebase` later, in [commit ad8261d2122](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad8261d21221d27638c75f47b39892db6f7972f6).)

I personally like to run `git fetch` first, then inspect its output and often run `git log` second, before running `git merge` or `git rebase` third.  If you use `git pull`, inserting the second command is literally impossible.

I also find that for someone new to Git, teaching `git fetch` separately, then `git merge` and `git rebase`, and only *then* noting that `git pull` combines these two steps, results in much more ability to *use* Git effectively.  It also provides the reason for the odd syntax that works only with `git pull`, i.e., why this is `origin master` and not `origin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it is the same.

Running a `git pull` runs the commands `git fetch origin` and `git merge origin/master`.

But you can change the default merge strategy to e.g. rebase merge. In this case, `git pull` will do a `git rebase` instead of a `git pull`.

As you can see [here](https://coderwall.com/p/tnoiug/rebase-by-default-when-doing-git-pull), you can configure the `git pull` command to use rebase merging by running `git config --global pull.rebase true` (you can use `--local` if you only want to do this in one repository).

See [the documentation of `git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) for details.